# How to deal with Imaginary Value of Fast Discrete Curvelet Coefficient?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, machine-learning

I want to classify the mean, energy, std, and entropy of discrete curvelet coefficients(wrapping) with Neural Net. But Neural Net can't deal with imaginary value. I have 2 option, either make it real (remove the imaginary, keep the real) or absolute it ( the imaginary become real). Which one i should choose and why?

e.g. :

abs(3+ 2i) = 5

real(3 + 2i) = 3